# Regular expressions in JavaScript using [\w.]+ instead of.+

Tags: javascript, regex

In the book JavaScript the Definite Guide 6th edition by David Flanagan there is an example of using regular expression:

For example, consider parsing a URL with the following code:

```
var url = /(\w+):\/\/([\w.]+)\/(\S*)/;
var text = "Visit my blog at http://www.example.com/~david";

var result = text.match(url);
if (result != null) 
{
    var fullurl = result[0];   // Contains "http://www.example.com/~david"  
    var protocol = result[1];  // Contains "http"    
    var host = result[2];      // Contains "www.example.com"
    var path = result[3];      // Contains "~david" 
}
```

I wonder why inside 2nd parenthesized expression he uses `[\w.]+` not just `.+`?

Comment: `[\w.]` matches a subset of what `.` matches, they're not equivalent. Why do think `. ` would be appropriate here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the risk of being downvoted, I am going to say that David Flanagan actually has a typo in his regex.  As @nnnnnn mentioned in his comment, the `.` dot metacharacter *includes* `\w`, so the character class `[\w.]+` is no different from `(.)+`.  Also note that `(\w)+` is *not* sufficient to capture the domain of the URL, because it contains periods, which `\w` does *not* match.  So, I believe David intended the following regex:

```
var url = /(\w+):\/\/(.+)\/(\S*)/;
```